# Why does Morpheus believe in the Oracle so much?

Tags: the-matrix

Some characters in The Matrix (like Commander Lock, etc) seem to have no faith in the Oracle.

But Morpheus believes so much in her. Is there any reason?

Comment: If a woman can talk about a vase you’d break in the future, you’d want to believe her for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morpheus' faith in the Oracle and her predictions seems to come from the fact that she has supported the Zionese rebels from the very start of their rebellion and that she appears to be able to see the future.

> **Morpheus:** *When the Matrix was first built, there was a man born inside who had the ability to change whatever he wanted, to remake the Matrix as he saw fit. It was he who freed the first of us, taught us the truth: ‘As long as the Matrix exists the human race will never be free.’ After he died the Oracle prophesized his return and that his coming would hail the destruction of the Matrix, end the war, bring freedom to our people. That is why there are those of us who have spent our entire lives searching the Matrix looking for him*

Unbeknownst to him, [she has her own agenda](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81893/20774) (who doesn't) and her prophecies have led the previous Zionese rebels (whose existence Morpheus is unaware of) to their inevitable deaths.